# Issue when sharing a Wicket DataProvider between DataViews

Tags: java, wicket

My web page displays two tables, which show a different view on the same data.

The tables are supported by Wicket DataView objects, which make use of a DataProvider to supply the data for the tables.

Now because the two tables are showing a different view of the same data, I'm sharing the same DataProvider bettween both DataViews.

However in my DataProvider, I can't see a way of determining which DataView is requesting the data. Is there a way I can differentiate between the two, at the point where I'm getting the data? Some way of knowing which table I'm dealing with is needed so I can filter the data accordingly.

What's the best approach to this?

Comment: Without knowing much about what you want to achieve, why can't you define an overridable method in your DataProvider, and let the views using it implement it to provide specific logic?

Comment: That might just work. Thanks Xavi.

Comment: Nice. I'll post that comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an overridable method in your `DataProvider` that will perform the specific logic, or get information on which logic to perform, and implement it by means of anonymous subclasses in the views that are instantiating it. This way you can delegate some of the logic (or data requerired to perform it) into the views that use the `DataProvider`.

Please note this is the lazy version of subclassing your DataProvider into public classes and using them straight in the views.